# Does Android Backup Service work at IceCreamSandwitch?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, restore, android-backup-service

My application uses [Android Backup Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).

When app installed on device, `onRestore()` method of my own `BackupAgent` usually calls, but when I use it on devices with Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 15) or higher, method `onRestore()` does **not** called at all!

Both system options ("Backup my data" and "Automatic restore") in "Backup & reset" of Settings are enabled.

Does anybody know, why `onRestore()` doesn't called on ICS+ devices?

Comment: Can you add more information?  The difference is likely caused by something other than being on ICS. onRestore() definitely works and is called on ICS.

Comment: When I use ICS, I don't receive any information about backuped data. Whn I use another Android, I receivw it, even if it is empty.

Comment: Are you testing this using local transport and bmgr?  If not you need to in order to remove the Google transport from the equation.

Comment: I tested it with using of bmgr, an it didn't work

Comment: I really doubt this is an issue directly related to your API level. Always test with the local transport.  What Google's transport does is undocumented - it oftentimes does not provide restore data which is why restore on Android is so hit and miss.